# Where do I wrong ? I don't get expected output

Tags: c, rounding

I try to write the code according to the problem. But I face problem with rounding issue. Can anyone explain me where I face the problem ?

> M=12, T=20, X=8  tip=(20×12)/100=2.4  tax=(8×12)/100=0.96  final
>   price=12+2.4+0.96=15.36  Officially, the price of the meal is $15.36,
>   but rounded to the nearest
>   dollar (integer), the meal is $15.

Here's My Full Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int t, x;
    double m;
    scanf("%lf", &m);
    scanf("%d", &t);
    scanf("%d", &x);
    double tip, tax;

    tip= m*t/100;
    tax= t*x/100;
    int total= (int)(round( tip + tax +m ));

    printf("The final price of the meal is $%d.", total);
    return 0;
}
```

When I take input `15.91,15,10` it shows output `19` instead of `20`

Where have I made mistakes?

Comment: Why is tax calculated on t instead that m?

Comment: No that is not your complete code.

Comment: `t` and `x` are not declared.

Comment: Seems like I missed those lines when I copy paste the codes. I edit those lines. Please check it again

Comment: I entered it into my calculator and found that `tip+tax+m` is 19,2965. Please be aware, that `tax = t*x/100` is an integer operation and rounded down to 1.

Comment: `tax=t*x/100;` is an integer calculation, before assigning the value to `double`.

Comment: @user3386109 multiplication and division have the same precedence and the associativity is from left to right. Thus, it first multiplys `m*t` there, and returns a double.

Comment: Especially because of your title: _Rounding in C Wrong Output_, I would think you would want to include the _round()_ function.  Are you using GNU extensions?

Comment: As @Jack has already alluded to. It seems `tax=t*x/100;` should be `tax=m*x/100;`. That will give the expected `$20` result.

Comment: I guess I have to add more info the question

Comment: Here's my problem statement : M=12, T=20, X=8 
tip=(20×12)/100=2.4 
tax=(8×12)/100=0.96 
final price=12+2.4+0.96=15.36 
Officially, the price of the meal is $15.36, but rounded to the nearest dollar (integer), the meal is $15.

Comment: Why do people give it so much down vote ?

Comment: because (at least I don't get your issue) ... 15,4 is rounded down to 15? oh AND because of your quite .. presumptuous title. C's rounding is fine for sure :)

Comment: Read the question properly `rounded to the nearest dollar (integer)` so I think 15.4 should be 15 not 16 Right mate ?

Comment: I thought I made mistake in round but I found the issue where I made my mistake. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do
`tax= t*x/100;`
you are making an integer division, so it will be rounded.

You will have **15*10/100 = 1**, instead of **1.5**

Also, you have `t*x` instead of `m*x`, as you put on your question

```
M=12, T=20, X=8 
tip=(20×12)/100=2.4 
     T  M
tax=(8×12)/100=0.96 
     X M
```

Change it to

`tip= m*t/100.0; 
 tax= m*x/100.0;`

And you will get the expected 20 as the final result

Comment: okay consider the input `12.00 20 8` the output would be `15` but your code shows `16`. The way you write the code it would pass only 1 test case but in other test case it would fall.

Comment: No, that is incorrect.  Because `m`, `t`, and `x` are defined as `double`, the division _will_ be floating point, even without `100.0`

Comment: I implement the same logic both java and python and it works perfectly. But it shows the wrong output in C

Comment: @CraigEstey `t` and `x` are `int`, I tested with her the first example and got 1 instead of 1.5

Comment: You are correct. `100` [only] works for `tip`, but best as `100.0` for consistency.  I tested also, but used `double` everywhere [by mistake].

Comment: Okay next time I won't this mistake again.